# Largest interval for existence of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the first order IVP:
$$\sin(t)y' + y=\frac{\sin(t)}{\ln(t-1)}, \qquad y\left({2\pi\over3}\right)=17$$
How to prove that the largest interval where the solution to the above problem is certain to exist is $(2,\pi)$?

I know that $f(x,y)=1/\ln(t-1) -y/\sin(t)$ is continuous and bounded inside the open rectangle of width $|t-\frac{2\pi}3|<\frac\pi3$ but unable to make a guess for height. Kindly help.

Comment: What is "In(t- 1)"?  Did you mean "ln(t- 1)"?  The first is a capital "i" the second a lower case "l".

Comment: it is natural logarithm.